# Rails: Why does user.attributes.keys only work with a newly created user, and not one I found (find_by) or pulled with .where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Thanks in advance for your help. Ruby on Rails noob here.

I'm trying to wrap my head around ActiveRecord. Specifically, once something has been saved to the db, how do I then pull it from the db, and manipulate it.

I have a `User` table and a `Messages` table. User `has_many` Messages, Messages `belongs_to` User.

In the Rails Console, as an example, if I create a `User` and store it in a variable `@created_user` via:

```
@created_user = User.create(from_number: "1234")
```

then try to run `@created_user.attributes.keys` I get the correct information. (A list of JUST the keys for `@created_user`.)

However, if I pull a user from the db instead via:

```
@looked_up_user = User.where(from_number: "12345")
```

I get the user properly pulled up. (The console shows me the SELECT statement, and what it pulled, and it's correct.)

However, when I run:

```
@looked_up_user.attributes.keys
```

I get `undefined method 'attributes'`

Why is attributes accessible only on a freshly created db element, instead of anything I assign to a variable?

If I wanted to see all of the keys inside the `@looked_up_user` variable, how would I do so?

Sorry for the basic question here, I just can't get my head around the documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.where` returns a `Relation`, not the model instance, upon instecting in console - it looks like an array with your objects.

You can do `User.where(from_number: "12345").first.attributes.keys`
or `User.find_by_from_number("12345").attributes.keys`

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way for me to pull up the model instance when I call the db?   Instead of User.where  is there a User.something I can do to pull up the model instance?

Comment: @PhilipCortes examples are in the answer, the catch is in that query with `where` may fetch more than one (or none) objects, so think of return value as of kind of an array

Comment: @PhilipCortes you're welcome. If that helped you - consider "accepting" the answer

Comment: Ah, just realized I had to do that. Sorry about that!

Comment: One other way to do this query and get a single instance is by using the find_by() method. These tend be a little cleaner then dynamic methods when you are passing in multiple attributes...  User.find_by(from_number: 12345, is_active: true)